# Mysql wild character for displaying all values in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
       Select distinct abc from xyz table where year="_____"
```

In where clause i want to put some wild characters which displays all the values of year.

Thank you

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but if you want to display all the values of `year`, then maybe you should not be using the `where` clause at all?

Comment: any sample wild card character?

Comment: do you care about a specific year? if not just leave it out. if so you could use `select distinct abc from xyz where YEAR(datecolumn) LIKE '199%'`. this will return all entries from 199x.

Answer (score 2):

try this

Select distinct abc from xyz table where year LIKE "%your value%"

it will fetch all matching records

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to use the keyword LIKE?

```
SELECT DISTINCT abc FROM xyz WHERE YEAR LIKE '201%'
```

Something like this would return all years that start with 201*, could be 2010 to 2019.